# Sum value if I have in another cell specific text (but SUMIF not working for it) - EXCEL

Tags: excel, sum

I need to get automatic sum when I have specific name in Column. For example

```
A1 - John, B1 - some product, C1 - 1
A2 - John, B2 - some product, C2 - 2
A3 - Tim, B3 - some product, C3 - 3
```

and I need get one table, where will be - John 3, Tim 3, but sumif not working for me (sumifs too).

Comment: SUMIF should work for this - what result did you get when you tried SUMIF? What was the formula you used?

Comment: You can use pivot table.

Comment: ou, my bad,  pivot table - the simplest solution!

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in your range and sum_range, among the parameters of SUMIF. And check F4 key, for absolute references just in case.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=ko-KR&rs=en-001&ad=KR&omkt=en-001

Say you have

```
F1 - John
F2 - Tim
```

for your sumif data.

Then G1 will be

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$3,F1,$C$1:$C$3)
```

for what you want.